# HAProxy wildcard SSL backend forward issue

Tags: ssl, wildcard, virtualhost, haproxy

I am using HAProxy 1.5-dev21. I have purchased a wildcard SSL (for example: *.foo.com). 
I want all traffic from Internet port 443 will redirect to internal network according the domain name, backend servers are many web server running HTTP (for example: abc.foo.com:443 -> 192.168.10.10:80  ,  edf.foo.com:443 -> 192.168.10.11:80)
However, whatever the incoming domain name, HAProxy passed all traffic to default backend.

My config is working well if I not using SSL
The following is my simplified config file:

```
global
    log     127.0.0.1 local0
    log     127.0.0.1 local1 notice
    maxconn 4096

defaults
    log     global
    mode    http
    option  tcplog
    timeout connect 5000ms
    timeout client 50000ms
    timeout server 50000ms

frontend https-in
    mode tcp
    bind :443 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/foo.com.pem
    use_backend abc if { hdr_end(host) -i abc.foo.com }
    use_backend def if { hdr_end(host) -i def.foo.com }
    default_backend application-backend

backend abc
    mode tcp
    server Server1 192.168.10.10:80

backend def
    mode tcp
    server Server2 192.168.10.11:80

backend application-backend
    mode tcp
    server server3 192.168.10.12:80
```

Comment: Did you successfully fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You're using tcp mode while trying to access HTTP content.
Please turn on 'mode http' and it should work.

Baptiste

Comment: I have changed to "mode http", however all traffic still passed to default_backend

Answer (score 0):

When you have of SSL, you can't use hdr_end. Here is how i do it:

```
frontend domain.com
        bind 10.50.81.131:443 ssl crt domain.com ciphers ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv3:+EXP
        bind 10.50.81.131:80
        mode http
        maxconn 300
        option httpclose
        option forwardfor
        reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https if { ssl_fc }
        use_backend first_farm if { ssl_fc_sni sub1.domain.com }
        use_backend second_farm if { ssl_fc_sni sub2.domain.com }
        default_backend default_farm
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have tried sni instead of hdr_end before, it still not working. I used your config, however, all traffic still passed to default_backend.